# jQuery ComboBox - Event (mouse enter / hover) for options in list

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, hover, mouseover, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the code example found [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) and would like to add a function that will create a tooltip with a message when the user hover over an option in the combobox. The tooltip must appear on hover for every option.

At this stage, I just wish to get the event to fire, the message in it self can be anything that I will define later. Can someone please help?

here is my code:

```js
      $( function() {
        $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
          _create: function() {
            this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
              .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
              .insertAfter( this.element );
     
            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton();
            this._hoverOption();
          },
       
       
    /*
    *
    * Hover Event
    *
    */
          _hoverOption: function() {},
       
    
          _createAutocomplete: function() {
            var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
              value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
     
            this.input = $( "<input>" )
              .appendTo( this.wrapper )
              .val( value )
              .attr( "title", "" )
              .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
              .autocomplete({
                delay: 0,
                minLength: 0,
                source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
              })
              .tooltip({
                classes: {
                  "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
                }
              });
     
            this._on( this.input, {
              autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.item.option.selected = true;
                this._trigger( "select", event, {
                  item: ui.item.option
                });
              },
     
              autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
            });
          },
     
          _createShowAllButton: function() {
            var input = this.input,
              wasOpen = false;
     
            $( "<a>" )
              .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
              .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
              .tooltip()
              .appendTo( this.wrapper )
              .button({
                icons: {
                  primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                },
                text: false
              })
              .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
              .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
              .on( "mousedown", function() {
                wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
              })
              .on( "click", function() {
                input.trigger( "focus" );
     
                // Close if already visible
                if ( wasOpen ) {
                  return;
                }
     
                // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
              });
          },
     
          _source: function( request, response ) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
      var result = [];
            result = this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
              var text = $( this ).text();
              if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                return {
                  label: text,
                  value: text,
                  option: this
                };
            }); 
      if(result.length == 1 && request.term.length > this.options.previousValue.length ){
        result[0].option.selected = true;
        this._trigger( "select", null, {
         item: result[0].option
        });
        this.input.val(result[0].label);
        this.options.previousValue = result[0].label;
      }else{
       this.options.previousValue = request.term;  
      }
      response(result);
      
          },
     
          _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
     
            // Selected an item, nothing to do
            if ( ui.item ) {
              return;
            }
     
            // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
            var value = this.input.val(),
              valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
              valid = false;
            this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
              if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
                this.selected = valid = true;
                return false;
              }
            });
     
            // Found a match, nothing to do
            if ( valid ) {
              return;
            }
     
          },
     
          _destroy: function() {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
          }
        });
     
        $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    
      } );
```

```css
li.ui-menu-item {
 padding-left: 15px; 
}

.custom-combobox {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 40px;
  }
  
.custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
  }

.custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



  <select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="good">one</option>
    <option value="bad">two</option>
    <option value="ugly">three</option>

  </select>
```

In solving this it is important to keep in mind that the jQuery procedure hides the original list. It creates a new list with a ul li structure.

Because of this, creating an event for the option list won't work for hover, because the user cannot interact with the original list as jQuery do that on behalf of the user.

When the user selects an option, jQuery updates the original option list.

Thus, in order for a mouseover / hover / mouseenter event to work here, it must be binded to the list created by jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

See code above from my initial post

Find:

```
  _hoverOption: function() {},
```

replace with:

```
  _hoverOption: function() {

      var input = this.input;

      input.autocomplete( "widget" ).each(function() {

          $(this).on('mouseenter', "li", function(){

               //tooltip logic

              });

        });

      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mouseover() jQuery method.

https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  //For each option in the combobox select
  $('select#combobox option').each(function(){
      // attach an mouseover event
      $(this).on('mouseover', function(){
           //your tooltip logic

      });
  });
});
```

Fiddle for you : http://jsfiddle.net/4BTyH/308/

Comment: I am afraid it does not fire.

Comment: @JacquesJoubert it should fire when you hover your mouse over option (and not click on option)

Comment: On its own it works fine, however in my sample I included it does not work. Its because its not just a selectbox but also a textbox

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to fill tooltips for each item at the same time data populates the comboBox:

```
$.each(prdtFiltered, function() {
                        producto.append($("<option />").val(this.cod_producto).text(this.producto_nombre).attr("title",this.descripcion));
                    });
```

In this example, the var prdtFIltered is json.